# system variable configuration in teamcity for adding timestamp to it

Tags: teamcity

I have created a parameter in Team city that is system parameter as shown below
system.version and its value is gla so it is like

```
system.version=gla
```

now can you please advise in Team City how can I configure this variable such as i want date time stamp to be appended since this variable is need to be changed every time when my build runs so I want to add the dates time stamp to this system variable please advise how to achieve this in team city.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an initial build step that writes out a [service message](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter) to update the parameter value (example below in PowerShell):

**Step 1**

```
$date = Get-Date
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='system.version' value='gla$date']"
```

**Step x**

```
Write-Host '%system.version%' # will output the new value
```

Comment: can you please advise how we van configure it in teamcity in add parameters sections itself

Comment: I don't see any way to solve this other than using a service message.  The internal TeamCity properties don't look like they contain the build date, so parameter substitution isn't an option.  What's the issue with adding a build step that does what my answer describes?

Comment: thanks , I am using ant so can i paste this lines, will it work in ant too , or can you please advise how to add the same in Ant too

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom build step that calls a shell command and appends date/time to your variable

```
#!/bin/bash
date_var=`date +%Y%M` --> Define your format here
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='system.version' value='$date_var']"
```

PS: you can use the new value of your variable only from the next build step

Comment: You might need to escape the "%" with an extra "%" or TeamCity might think %Y% is a built in parameter. Like this: date_var=`date +%%Y%%M`